# display success message from PHP POST with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form which I would like to display a success message when the server returns a 200 code as a response from a POST method.

It seems like AJAX is the way to do this, but as I am relatively new to even vanilla JS, I cant work out the way to implement this. What is the function needed to 'listen' to the server response?

If not AJAX, how would you go about it?

EDIT to include code example

PHP

```
<?php

$data = array(

  "applicants"=> [
    array(
      "email"=> $_POST["email"],
      "firstName"=> $_POST["firstName"],
      "lastName"=> $_POST["lastName"],
      "telephone"=> $_POST["telephone"]
    )
  ],
  "buyerType" => $_POST["buyerType"],
);

$data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = [
  "x-api-key: xxxxxx",
  "accept: application/json",
  "content-Type: application/json",
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.smartr365.com/api/v1/mortgage/lead/create');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
var_dump($response);
// TO DEBUG ---
// $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
//var_dump($data);
var_dump($status_code);
// var_dump($response);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

The Javascript is too long to show, as it has quite extensive validation, but the crux of the script, which enables the 'submit' button is:

```
// final validation for the form
const checkBox = document.getElementById("accept");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitButton");

checkBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let valid = false;
    let isFormValid = false;
    if (checkFirstName() == valid &&
        checkLastName() == valid &&
        checkEmail() == valid &&
        checkTelephone() == valid) {
        isFormValid = true;
    }
    if (checkBox.checked && isFormValid == true) {
        submitBtn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        submitBtn.disabled = true;
    }
});


// real time validation
const debounce = (fn, delay = 500) => {

    let timeoutId;

    return (...args) => {
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            fn.apply(null, args)
        }, delay);
    };
};
//event delegation
form.addEventListener('input', debounce(function(e) {
    switch (e.target.id) {
        case 'firstName':
            checkFirstName();
            break;
        case 'lastName':
            checkLastName();
            break;
        case 'email':
            checkEmail();
            break;
        case 'telephone':
            checkTelephone();
            break;
    }
}));
```

Comment: You can do it with or without AJAX. First familiarise yourself with HTML forms + PHP (or other server side code), there are plenty of tutorials about it. Then you can move onto using AJAX if you want to offer a different user experience. There are a billion and one tutorials for that too which will show you how to receive a response back from the server.

Comment: I have the form, the javascript and the php written, The form can send data to the API endpoint, and the javascript works for real time form validation. What I want is to keep the user on the page, and display a success message.

Comment: Ok so please show the existing code and explain where you're stuck. Then we can suggest improvments / fixes. That's how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: I know, Its not that I'm stuck on a piece of code, its that I'm stuck with the concept and how to implement. But I will show my code

Comment: Well basically you supply a callback function which the browser will run as and when it gets a response from the server. But _exactly_ how you do that depends on which of the many AJAX libraries out there you're using to make the request.

Comment: Ok. There's no AJAX there at all. Have you followed any AJAX tutorials? I would generally suggest using the modern fetch() API for it, which is built into all modern browsers and is fairly easy to use. Stackoverflow doesn't provide tutorials (because there are 1000s of those already) but we will answer specific questions about an issue in your AJAX code, if/when you've attempted to write some.

Comment: Okay thankyou, I didnt know where to start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245990/discussion-between-yenmangu-and-adyson).